# Laravel query using with() method with unproper sub-query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I perform the following query with no problem. But it doesn't get the results I want.

I want 3 comments for each post, but I think it gets 3 comments totally. How can I resolve this?

```
$posts = Post::with([   
                    'comments' => function($c) {
                                    $c->orderBy('commentTimestamp', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
                                            }
                    ])
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is totally valid, I just ran it myself and got the right results, please check your database, if you do `SELECT * FROM comments` do you get records?